# Is there a method to group the arguments together in Python

Tags: python, input

This program I created asks the user for three values, and tells the user if he entered 1, 2 or 3 unique strings. But I feel it looks very repetitive:

```
def num_unique(v1, v2, v3):
    vlist = []
    if v1 not in vlist:
        vlist.append(v1)
    if v2 not in vlist:
        vlist.append(v2)
    if v3 not in vlist:
        vlist.append(v3)
    return len(vlist)
```

How can I group the arguments together and loop through them rather than listing them out 1 by 1?

Grateful for all the help, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use set:

```py
def num_unique(v1, v2, v3):
    return len(set((v1, v2, v3)))

print(num_unique(1,2,3)) # 3
print(num_unique(1,1,3)) # 2
```

You can reduce repetition (of typing `v1`, `v2`, `v3`) further by [`*args`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#arbitrary-argument-lists), which also adds flexibility:

```py
def num_unique(*nums):
    return len(set(nums))

print(num_unique(1,2,3)) # 3
print(num_unique(1,1,3,3)) # 2
```

Answer (score 1):

Lets say

```py
prompt = "Enter a string: "
unique_strings = set([input(prompt) for i in range(3)])
print(len(unique_strings))
```

Not in a form of a function, but fine:D

About the use of [set](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#sets)